# Workflow not be triggered when first approver click approve button

Tags: workflow, infopath

There is a problem has pluzzed me for a week, so come here and ask everyone for assistance. 
I have two form view (using infopath rule to change) :
1. Appply Form 
  "Submit" button => set "Action" field value to "SE" by rule  ,
                     and it will trigger workflow to start approval process on 
         Leader 
[image]

2. Leader View  (When workflow to Leader)

[image]

before click Approve button , leader need to assign Onwer1 
  "Approve" button => set "Action" field value to "TA" by rule , and then 
 trigger workflow to owner1

3. Workflow Setting
   [image]

4. Workflow Condition
   [image]

when submit apply form , it OK

[image]

but the problem is ,when leader assign owner1 and click approve button, workflow not trigger ...

[image]

I really don't know why and how to resolve this question..

Thank you all ~

Comment: i think you should move your "Leader Approval" workflow code block after "the wait for Action to not equal SE"  or  if these two are created as stage then use "Go to stage" action after  "the wait for Action to not equal SE"  and put the "Go to stage" value as "Leader Approval" .

Answer (score 0):

In central admin there is a timer job called workflow. I would check that timer job to see what interval it is set at or if it is failing.

To view the workflow timer job:

1. go to central admin-->monitoring-->
2. under timer jobs click on review job definitions

[image]

3. locate timer job "workflow"

[image]

4. From here you'll be able to see how often this timer job runs. Mine is set to run every 5 minutes.

To see if that timer job is failing:

1. In the same section as the job definition there will be a link on the left hand side called job history.

[image]

2. filter the list to failed jobs and search for the workflow timer job

[image]

Looking at these items might help determine if the workflow isn't being triggered because of something outside of the workflow itself.